# How to set default value in Grid?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a selector control, and I want to set a default value when user click on "+" button, I have tried field defaulting event, CacheAttached and RowInserted also but none of them are working.

Below is code for reference.

```
//Cache Attached
[PXDBString(4, IsFixed = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = "####")]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<AMShiftMst.shiftID, Where<AMShiftMst.shiftID, Equal<AMShiftID>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<AMShiftMst.shiftID>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Shift")]
protected virtual void AMShift_ShiftID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{

}

//RowInserted
protected virtual void AMShift_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e, PXRowInserted InvokeBaseHandler)
{
    if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(sender, e);

    AMShift row = e.Row as AMShift;

    if (row == null)
        return;

    row.ShiftID = "1";            
}

//Defaulting Event
protected virtual void AMShift_ShiftID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    AMShift doc = e.Row as AMShift;

    if (doc != null)
    {
        AMShiftMst AMShiftMstData = PXSelectReadonly<AMShiftMst, Where<AMShiftMst.shiftID, Equal<Required<AMShiftMst.shiftID>>>>.Select(Base, "1");

        if (AMShiftMstData != null)
        {
            e.NewValue = AMShiftMstData.ShiftID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try RowInserting.

Comment: Hello HB_Acumatica, I tried but not sure why it is not working

Comment: Hello HB_Acumatica, i was missing <Mode InitNewRow="true" /> grid property, i have fixed it.

Comment: Hello, am using field defaulting event to set the value and it is working as expected but when i click on save button the values are getting cleared, may i know what may be reason, thanks

Comment: the value comes back empty? or comes back with the fixed spacing as its a fixed length field ("1   ") ? Could be another event clearing or cancelling the value.

Comment: Hello Brendan, i have verified field value in grid DAC row persisting event and they are coming as null, as you said may be some other event clearing the values, because i have extended graph of some other project and working on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults the way you have them work, however they require the user to enter in a new row first. In this graph it would require the user to at least fill out one field value to get the defaults to trigger.

I updated my code from my previous answer to include an automatic insert of the row which then using your defaults will automatically set the values. Note you can also move the global SetVisible calls to Initialize as I have shown below.

```
public class MyGraphExtensionTest : PXGraphExtension<WCMaint>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<AMShift.crewSize>(Base.WCShifts.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<AMShift.machNbr>(Base.WCShifts.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<AMShift.shftEff>(Base.WCShifts.Cache, null, false);
    }

    protected virtual void AMWC_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e, PXRowInserted del)
    {
        if (del != null)
        {
            del(sender, e);
        }

        var row = (AMWC) e.Row;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row?.WcID) || Base.IsImport || Base.IsContractBasedAPI || Base.WCShifts.Cache.Inserted.Any_())
        {
            return;
        }

        Base.WCShifts.Insert(new AMShift
        {
            WcID = row.WcID
        });
    }

    protected virtual void AMShift_ShiftID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e, PXFieldDefaulting del)
    {
        if (del != null)
        {
            del(sender, e);
        }

        AMShift doc = e.Row as AMShift;

        if (doc != null)
        {
            AMShiftMst AMShiftMstData = PXSelect<AMShiftMst, Where<AMShiftMst.shiftID, Equal<Required<AMShiftMst.shiftID>>>>.Select(Base, "1");

            if (AMShiftMstData != null)
            {
                e.NewValue = AMShiftMstData.ShiftID;
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void AMShift_CalendarID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e, PXFieldDefaulting del)
    {
        if (del != null)
        {
            del(sender, e);
        }

        AMShift doc = e.Row as AMShift;

        if (doc != null)
        {
            CSCalendar CSCalendarData = PXSelect<CSCalendar, Where<CSCalendar.calendarID, Equal<Required<CSCalendar.calendarID>>>>.Select(Base, "OFFICE");

            if (CSCalendarData != null)
            {
                e.NewValue = CSCalendarData.CalendarID;
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void AMShift_LaborCodeID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e, PXFieldDefaulting del)
    {
        if (del != null)
        {
            del(sender, e);
        }

        AMShift doc = e.Row as AMShift;

        if (doc != null)
        {
            AMLaborCode AMLaborCodeData = PXSelect<AMLaborCode, Where<AMLaborCode.laborCodeID, Equal<Required<AMLaborCode.laborCodeID>>>>.Select(Base, "DIRECT");

            if (AMLaborCodeData != null)
            {
                e.NewValue = AMLaborCodeData.LaborCodeID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Brendan, am really sorry to say but this is not working, i have grid with only three fields visible, ShiftID, CalendarID and LaborCode and am defaulting values for these fields. But if i set value for only two fields and manually select other field value then it is not causing any issue. Please let me know if you wanna see my code file i can share with you.

Comment: If you can please share. You can use something like https://pastebin.com/ and share the link here in the comment

Comment: Thanks for help Brendan, here is the file https://pastebin.com/P1N83Vtz

Comment: thanks. Can you also confirm the version of JAMS & Acumatica you are using?

Comment: Acumatica version 17.210.0034, JAMS version - MFG - 17.210.0034.42 - 2018.06.06

Comment: The code works. The problem is the default is not going to fire until you fill out something in the row. So if you start a new row and enter the shift and save the values are filled in.

Comment: Updated answer with logic to auto insert the row so the defaults can trigger the values.

Comment: Thank you very much Brendan :)